# Measure of Spread of Geometric Points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let X and Y be two sets of points in n-dimensional Euclidean space.

I would like to compare how 'densely concentrated' the points in each set are.

1) My initial thought is to calculate the average of distances between all of the points in a set. This seems simplistic, but at least it is easy to calculate.

2) I thought about using the concept of convex hull and calculating the 'volume' of the resulting shape. I have a feeling that in dimension higher than 2 this might be very tricky.

I am really wondering if there is something somewhere in-between these two ideas.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the [bomb problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalEnclosingCircle.html#:~:text=The%20minimal%20enclosing%20circle%20problem,as%20the%20minimal%20enclosing%20circle.&text=Given%20Points%20in%20a%20Plane.%22%20Proc.)

Comment: The first method is probably the best way. For your sets of points X and Y, compute $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$

Answer (score 1):

There are several notions of *statistical depth* you might explore.
One is *halfspace depth*:

> Zuo, Yijun. "A new approach for the computation of halfspace depth in high dimensions." *Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation* 48, no. 3 (2019): 900-921.
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Fig.1 in Zuo.</sup>

---

A second notion is [*simplicial depth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_depth).
A third is *projection depth*.